# How can we call logout servlet on internet disconnection or if user closes tab/browser?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

i want to avoid concurrent login with same username and password, for this i have set a isloggedin option in database, if user logs in it will become '1',so with that username and password he can't login again, if he calls logout it will become '0' so he can login. everything is fine,but iam having problem when net disconnets or when user closes the tab. he cant login because isloggedin is set to '1',it should be avoided by setting it to one that means it should call logout servlet.how can i acheive this?

Answer (score 3):

There is no technique to surely notify the web server when the user closes the tab or browser.
following techniques may help you to terminate the user session after they are gone.

1. configure session-timeout in web.xml.
2. Set the age of cookie(if you are using any) equal to -1.So that it is deleted when browser closes.
3. You may have have a java script which sends some data(heartbeat) regularly to the server indicating that the session is active. (but this will keep the session active even if the user is idle for a long time)

Comment: Actually, there is a way to detect when the user has closed a page, using onbeforeunload callback, see my answer. Also using a heartbeat technique will always maintain your session active :(.

Comment: One easy way to avoid concurrent login is to place a cookie in the user's browser.Every time before logging in you have to check for the cookies if they are present that means your user is already logged in and you may simply redirect him to his profile or any page you like...hope it helps

Comment: Using a cookie on a browser will limit the number of logins from that browser/machine only. From another machine the same user will be able to login again. The proper way is to track the logins on server side.

Comment: I completely agree with Mr. Dan on this. cookies will only work for the current browser. Go for server side tracking only if your application really demands it.

Comment: this is the best answer IMO. From now on its up to @user1635967 how he wants his website to behave

Comment: Please avoid making sweeping statements like the first one you did without verification. Someone like me could just see that one line and run with it

Answer (score 2):

You should use spring-security for authenticating the users. Besides other benefits, you will be able to control how many concurrent logins will be allowed too, see 'Concurrent Session Control' from: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html
This way once the user will invalidate the session (by using a logout action) or by closing the browser page (you can catch that even too, see onbeforeunload event), even if the session will timeout because it's idle too much the spring-security framework will handle all the cases for you. This way you will not need to maintain that db value anymore.

Comment: See a tutorial from here: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/start-here.html on how to use spring security in your application.

Comment: Great save on `onbeforeunload`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a DB flag its better to use a List in server as a global parameter and add the username to this. So whenever user trys to login add the parameter to the List. Then if the user again trys to login to the session check in the List whether that username is available, if available remove from that session.

If using a DB it can cause DB overload. Keep DB free

Answer (score 0):

you just need to call a javascrip function on browser closing. you can add logic there to alter the session or restrict the user to close the window. its all upto you.
here is some reference code to guide you

```
<html><head><title>Example</title>
<script language = "JavaScript">
function abc()
{
statements...
}
</script></head>
<body ONUNLOAD = "abc()">
</html>
```

Comment: i have tried already onbeforeunload but these are the problems iam facing 1.It's called whenever the user navigates away from the page, refreshes, or generally unloads as well as when the browser window is closed.
There doesn't seem to be a consistent behaviour between browsers.

Comment: then you should set a minimum timeout like 1 minute, when the session expires you update the isloggedin, so that user can again login

Comment: if he closes the browser in less than one minute?

Comment: then no issue, the purpose of session expiry time is that after mentioned time, the session should be terminated.  when user again logins after session expiration, you would check his session and also isloggedin, if session is not there, you update the isloggedin and craete a new session for the user

Answer (score 0):

There is no consistent or 100% reliable way to detect disconnect/close browser, it's simply not addressed in the HTTP protocols. As has been mentioned, you can get a bit on the way with Javascript (`body onunload`), but that does not cover all scenarios and is not consistent across browsers.

The short answer here is that you should not design your system to rely on being able to detect the moment a user leaves your site (disconnect/navigate away/close window) since you can't.